# Picking bottom bracket and chain set for older mtb frame

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have  an old norco manik frame from 2006 and I need help picking bottom bracket and chainset.

I have been looking at Truvativ Hussefelt 1.1 DH Chainset at crc but how do I make sure the bottom bracket and chainset fit? The original bike spec just lists Truvativ Hussefelt as chainset, no specific bb is being mentioned.

Aiming at using this mtb as my winter bike not looking for exclusive parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few of ways to find out what will fit:

1. Research websites like [Bikepedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2006&brand=Norco&model=Manik) and [Norco.com](https://www.norco.com/archives/2006/bike_enlarged.php?lang=en&loc=fs&sloc=fr&tabloc=1&id=manik&col=blue) and check the original spec. You've possibly done this already and found it's of little help.
2. Pull the cranks off and remove the BB length and diameter will be printed on it. You're looking to take it off anyway.
3. Remove everything and measure, this will be most complicated and a last resort.

They're your three options, but with a bit of googling to confirm it's easy to find [threads](http://pinkbike.com/forum/listcomments/?threadid=122664) dealing with this. Essentially most North American mtbs of this age run a 68/73mm English threaded BB and a 47.5 or 50mm chain line. 2.5mm won't be a significant difference however.

As you are replacing crank and BB you only need to match what you buy, so if you get a square taper BB you need a square taper crank and so forth. The crank determines spindle length, not the frame. Shimano Hollowtech II cranks come with an external BB so always an easy option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the frame is "naked" has no BB to compare with. It's 68 mm wide but I get your point, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Different BB sizes and offsets can make this an expensive exercise (speaking from experience).

This is one I would use the LBS - pay someone with experience to do it, or utilise their shelf full of different sized BB's - buy one with a "right to return" if its not the right size.

Ideally take the bike in, they will probably give you the correct one first time. BB's a cheap enough the savings going internet/discount supplier are probably not worth the time and effort for the risk of getting the wrong size.